# Disable/Remove Warning about a not bound Render Target View

Tags: directx, directx11, shadow-mapping

So to render into my shadow map depthstencil buffer i only bind a DepthStencilView to the Output Merger. Like this

```
    m_pContext->OMSetRenderTargets(0,0, m_pShadowMapDV);
    m_pContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_pShadowMapDV, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
```

Now this works fine and my shadow-map also produces the desired result. What bothers me though is the constant warnings in the debug-window. Is there a way or trick to disable that warning?

```
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: The Pixel Shader expects a Render Target View bound to slot 0, but none is bound. This is OK, as writes of an unbound Render Target View are discarded. It is also possible the developer knows the data will not be used anyway. This is only a problem if the developer actually intended to bind a Render Target View here. [ EXECUTION WARNING #3146081: DEVICE_DRAW_RENDERTARGETVIEW_NOT_SET]
```

This might be a pretty dumb question, but after googling a lot i still came up empty. Only i a lot of people who are not doing this on purpose.

**EDIT:** Maybe the question can be asked in another way:

Is there a way to define an empty PixelShader? If i define the return value as void it notifies me, that i have to at least return the 4 pixel colors. If i don't give it any Semantics it does not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppresses messages from the debug layer:

```
#include <wrl/client.h>
using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

#ifndef NDEBUG
    ComPtr<ID3D11Debug> d3dDebug;
    hr = m_d3dDevice.As(&d3dDebug);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ComPtr<ID3D11InfoQueue> d3dInfoQueue;
        hr = d3dDebug.As(&d3dInfoQueue);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            D3D11_MESSAGE_ID hide [] =
            {
                D3D11_MESSAGE_ID_SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS,
                // TODO: Add more message IDs here as needed 
            };
            D3D11_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter;
            memset(&filter, 0, sizeof(filter));
            filter.DenyList.NumIDs = _countof(hide);
            filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
            d3dInfoQueue->AddStorageFilterEntries(&filter);
        }
    }
#endif
```

See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need the pixel shader (eg: you don't write to depth manually in there or don't use discard), you can just set the Pixel Shader stage to null.

Depth stencil will still be written to, and your warning message will disappear.

so just doing

```
deviceContext->PSSetShader(NULL,NULL,0);
```

Will do the trick.

It (should) also be faster since you don't even call the pixel shader at all.